# How do I read a null value in the IDataReader?

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine, idatareader

I'm using sqlite as a database. One of the value is null in my database. It's datatype is bytes. Following is the code that I use to retrieve the value,

```
        byte[] blobValue = new byte[iData.GetBytes(4,0,null,0,int.MaxValue)-1];
```

Unfortunately it throws "Invalid cast exception" as the data is empty. How do I return null if the data is empty in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`IsDBNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatarecord.isdbnull?view=net-5.0#System_Data_IDataRecord_IsDBNull_System_Int32_):

```
byte[] blobValue = null;
if(!iData.IsDBNull(4))
{
    blobValue = new byte[iData.GetBytes(4,0,null,0,int.MaxValue)-1];
}
```